# How can I seperate the find_element and switch_to codelines into different module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on the infrastructure for the GUI automation in my company. I am new to python and a total amateur in writing SW (my expertise is HW).

I started experimenting python and selenium and got to a point where I look forward and see a certain implementation problem.

The following is an example of a script that is actually a short test plan:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time


def main():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = i +1
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
        browser.implicitly_wait(20) # Implicit wait
        try:
            execute_code(i, browser)
            browser.quit()
            if i == 500:
                break
        except:
            browser.quit()

def Cold_Restart(browser):

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    SysBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('System')
    SysBtn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_menu')
    Mainten_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('Maintenance')
    Mainten_Btn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_restart')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab.click()

    browser.switch_to.frame('maint_sys')
    Cold_Rst_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('cold_restart')
    Cold_Rst_Btn.click()

    #In order to confirm the Alert Message I first need to switch to the alert pop-up message and then accept it
    alertDialog = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alertDialog.accept()

    time.sleep(205)

    return


def Port_Admin_Down(browser):

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    Port_19 = browser.find_element_by_id('Port-19')
    Port_19.click()


    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Show the Port Configuration TAB
    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    CFP2_Info = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_general')
    CFP2_Info.click()

    browser.switch_to.frame('config_port') # Move to the inner frame that holds the configuration fields and buttons

    Admin_Down_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('red_button')
    Admin_Down_Btn.click()

    #In order to confirm the Alert Message I first need to switch to the alert pop-up message and then accept it
    alertDialog = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alertDialog.accept()

    time.sleep(5)
    return


def Port_Admin_Up(browser):

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    Port_19 = browser.find_element_by_id('Port-19')
    Port_19.click()
    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Show the Port Configuration TAB
    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    CFP2_Info = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_general')
    CFP2_Info.click()

    browser.switch_to.frame('config_port') # Move to the inner frame that holds the configuration fields and buttons

    Admin_Down_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('green_button')
    Admin_Down_Btn.click()

    #In order to confirm the Alert Message I first need to switch to the alert pop-up message and then accept it
    alertDialog = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alertDialog.accept()    

    time.sleep(5)
    return

def Gui_Login(browser, URL):
    browser.get(URL)
#    browser.implicitly_wait(20) # Implicit wait


    browser.maximize_window()

    # Find the User Name text box and fill the User name
    user_name_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_name_box')
    user_name_box.click()
    user_name_box.send_keys('admin')

    # Find the Password text box and fill the Password
    user_pass_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_pass_box')
    user_pass_box.click()
    user_pass_box.send_keys('admin')

    #webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_id('login_but')
    login_button.click()

    return

def Gui_Logout(browser):

    browser.switch_to.default_content() # Get back to the default starting point


    # In order to click the Logout button I needed to pass through two frames
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    logout_btn = browser.find_element_by_id('Logout')
    logout_btn.click()

    return

def Sample_Uplink(browser):

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Go to the Configuration Pane (main_menu)
    browser.switch_to.frame('main_menu')
    Configuration_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('Configuration')
    Configuration_Btn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Go to the Uplink 1 CFP2 information and take the Rx Pwr
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    Port_19 = browser.find_element_by_id('Port-19')
    Port_19.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Show the Optic Module information TAB
    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    CFP2_Info = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_XFP')
    CFP2_Info.click()

    # Collect the Rx Pwr from the CFP2 Info screen
    browser.switch_to.frame('config_port') # Move to the inner frame that holds all the tables
    #browser.find_element_by_class_name('table_round_corner')
    Rx_Pwr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]') # Take the Rx Pwr according to its Xpath
    # print (Rx_Pwr.text) # print the Rx Pwr result to screen
    RcvPwr = Rx_Pwr.text

    # Collect the OSNR measurement from the CFP2 Info screen
    OSNR = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
    OSNR_Lvl = OSNR.text


#    time.sleep(5)
    return (RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl)



def Save_2_File(Rx_Pwr, OSNR_Lvl, i):
    file = open("test_results.txt", "a")
    file.write("%i. " %i)
    file.write(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y    ')) # Print Time & Date to the text file 
    file.write(Rx_Pwr) # Print the Rx_Pwr to the text file
    file.write('%10s' %(OSNR_Lvl)) # Format the placement of the OSNR value
    file.write('\n') # Make sure that the next iteration will write the results in the next line
    file.close() # Closing the file
    return


def execute_code(i, browser):

    #===========================================================================
    # Cold Restart Recovery test
    #===========================================================================
    URL1 = 'http://10.0.1.131' #  First device that will be Cold Restarted
    Gui_Login(browser, URL1)

    Cold_Restart(browser)
    (RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl) = Sample_Uplink(browser)
    Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl, i)

    URL2 = 'http://10.0.1.134'
    Gui_Login(browser, URL2)

    Cold_Restart(browser)
    (RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl) = Sample_Uplink(browser)
    Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl, i)


    #===========================================================================
    # Local Uplink Down --> Up
    #===========================================================================

    browser.get(URL1)

    Port_Admin_Down(browser)
    Port_Admin_Up(browser)

    time.sleep(5)

    browser.get(URL2)   

    #Get Rx Pwr and OSNR and save in file
    (RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl) = Sample_Uplink(browser)
    Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl, i)


    #===========================================================================
    # Remote Uplink Down --> Up
    #===========================================================================

    Port_Admin_Down(browser)
    Port_Admin_Up(browser)

    time.sleep(5)

    browser.get(URL1)   

    #Get Rx Pwr and OSNR and save in file
    (RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl) = Sample_Uplink(browser)
    Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl, i)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is that most of the script is actually find_elements and switch_frame commands. When I look forward, I want to see the Test Plan scripts cleaner while all the "dirty work" of finding (mapping) elements and switching frames is done in separate modules.

I separated these code lines into a different module and only then I realized that I have a certain problem. The browser variable is common to the module and the test script and shouldn't be opened twice (I think so).

How could this be done without losing the main objective which is the Test Plan?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about the Page Object Model design pattern. It targets what you are trying to achieve and it's in general a good practice

Comment: Thanks, POM exactly defines the concept that I'm looking for. Now I am looking for examples that were implemented in Python

Comment: There are a lot of examples in google. Generally, you need to switch to iframe in the constructor `(__init__)`. See POM [example](https://justin.abrah.ms/python/selenium-page-object-pattern--the-key-to-maintainable-tests.html).

Comment: @Buaban Why do I need to "switch to frame" in the constructor (__init__) ?

Comment: @MosheS. Because constructor will be invoked automatically. So you don't need to code to call switch to iframe.